# Stream socket client error: Cannot push notifications to mobile phones

Tags: php, wordpress, sockets, curl, push-notification

I just setup a codebase that sends push notifications to iphone and android mobiles
It works fine with index-notification.php but it does not work with the same code in other file:
The scenario is like this:

if a client sets the url link for push notifications, it goes there and run it and get the result back with curl
The external url link in question does the real push actions to mobiles with certified pem files
And that file really works well when i use it standalone
But when it runs as an external link like above the push actions don't occur any more with same device tokens and pem files

Can you help me out?

Here is the code for pushing notifications

```
function sendIOS_Push($message, $deviceToken, $pem, $pass, $env)
    {      
        $passphrase = trim($pass);

        $body['aps'] = array('alert' => $message,
                            'sound' => 'default',
                             );

        // Encode the payload as JSON
        $payload = json_encode($body);
        $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

        if($env == 'production') {
            $ctx = stream_context_create();
            stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $pem);

            if ($passphrase)
                stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);      
            $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
                                       $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

            if (!$fp)
                exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);    
            $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));  
            fclose($fp);
        }
        elseif($env == 'sandbox') {
           //Desvelopment push 
            $ctx = stream_context_create();
            stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $pem);

            if ($passphrase)
                stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

            $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
                                           $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

            if (!$fp)
                exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);      
            $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
            fclose($fp);
        }

        return 1;
    }
```

and here is the code for sending curl request to above file

```
$data = array(
    'devToken' => $tokenID,
    'device' => strtolower($device),
    'pass' => $pemPass,
    'body' =>$msg,
    'postID' =>$pRediredirectIDOrLink,
    'type' =>$pushType,
    'enviroment' => $enviroment,
    'cert'=>"http://".$cert
        );



        $ch = curl_init();

        if(get_option("amazingcart_ChooseHost") == 1)
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "".get_bloginfo( 'url' )."/?scrollblogkruk=apns");
        }
        else if(get_option("amazingcart_ChooseHost") == 2)
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://".get_option("amazingcart_externalServer")."");
        }

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I am using amazingcart plugin for wordpress and amazingcart requires additional url link for pushing notifications
and first code snippet does the exact thing and it works fine when i work with in a standalone project, but does not work when i refer it as a curl request (second snippet for sending curl to first code snippet)

Comment: Solved this issue finally
It was about configuration on push notification
i should have used the development mode not production and it worked for me